# Correct javascript syntax for using document.getElementById on a form with variables and iteration

Tags: javascript, forms, syntax, getelementbyid

I'm trying to send the contents of a div built from form data, to a hidden form field using javascript, but I can't get the syntax right.

All in the .js file, the form field looks like this

```
$('#ticketDetails').append ('<div id="seat-build-row-' + i + '" class="seller-listing row"> \
                   <input type="hidden" id="seatNumber-[' + i + ']" class="form-control seatNumber" name="ticket[' + i + '][seat_number]" value=""> \
               </div>');
```

and the div that I'm referencing is here

```
$('#ticket-rows').append('<div id="ticket-row-' + i + '" class="seller-listing row"> \
                  <div class="col-4 col-md-6" id="seatDetailsBuild-' + i + '">Section: <span class="seatSectionData"></span>, Row: <span class="seatRowData"></span>, Seat Number: <span class="seatNumData"></span></div> \
               </div>');
```

The three spans are filled using blur when form data is entered elsewhere, like this

```
$('.seatNum').off('blur').on('blur', function() {
                   var row = $('#ticket-row-' + $(this).parent().parent().data('row'));
                   row.find('.seatNumData').html($(this).val());

                   }
               });
```

So far so good (it all works fine), except I can work out the correct syntax for document.getelementbyId, because of the [' + i + '] in each row.
I have this, but it doesn't work

```
document.getElementById(seatNumber-[' + i + ']).value = document.getElementById("seatDetailsBuild-' + i + '").innerHTML;
```

With a simpler fixed id for seatNumber and seatDetailsBuild, it works fine (but only once).

Any help on the correct syntax greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @el-teedee, I have tried to keep it as simple as possible, only showing the relevant pieces of code. The document,getelementbyId syntax is the main issue here, but I thought some context might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have your quotes misplaced. They need to be around the listeral part of the ID, not the variable being concatenated.

```
document.getElementById('seatNumber-[' + i + ']')
```

BTW, I wouldn't recommend using `[]` in IDs, as it makes it harder to refer to the element using selector syntax, since square brackets are used for attribute selectors.